# jQuery - window resize event - add and remove variable from URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Okay so this is where im at currently... 
Basically im appending to the end of a url based on window width (works fine, using drawNewUrl()).

On window resize the page reload is supposed to remove the appended attribute  i add at the end of the URL ('?url/suffix/example/').. 
But instead it's not removing urlAppend at all (with jQuery(urlAppend).remove();), it continually adds urlAppend to the end of the url on window resize. (ie: example.com/?url/suffix/example/1/?url/suffix/example/1/). How would i remove urlAppend on resize and allow the new url to be drawn?

```
var urlAppend;

function drawNewUrl() {
    if (jQuery(window).width() > 1200) {
        var urlAppend = '?url/suffix/example/3/';
    }  else if (jQuery(window).width() > 768) {
        var urlAppend = '??url/suffix/example/2/';
    } else {
        var urlAppend = '?url/suffix/example/1/';
    }

    jQuery('.class').attr('href', function() {
        return this.href + urlAppend;
    });
}
jQuery(window).resize(function() {
    jQuery(urlAppend).remove();
    drawNewUrl();
});
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    drawNewUrl(); // for onload 
});
```

Comment: `urlAppend = ''` instead of  `jQuery(urlAppend).remove()` ?

Comment: @kasperite Hmmmm... This will not work for removing the attribute from the url.. only for resetting the variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try my solution and see if it works for you. I'm using regexp to conditionally add `urlAppend` to the `href` attribute.

```js
var urlAppend;

function drawNewUrl() {
    if (jQuery(window).width() > 1200) {
        var urlAppend = '?url/suffix/example/3/';
    }  else if (jQuery(window).width() > 768) {
        var urlAppend = '?url/suffix/example/2/';
    } else {
        var urlAppend = '?url/suffix/example/1/';
    }

    jQuery('.class').attr('href', function() {
     return this.href.replace(/(\?url\/suffix\/example\/\d\/)?$/i, urlAppend);
    });
}
jQuery(window).resize(function() {
    drawNewUrl();
});
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    drawNewUrl(); // for onload 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" class="class">
  Link 1
</a>
<a href="#" class="class">
  Link 2
</a>
<a href="#" class="class">
  Link 3
</a>
<a href="#" class="class">
  Link 4
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like this, working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/s22su/6wxmrebu/1/

```
var defaultUrl = 'hello.php';

function drawNewUrl() {
  var urlAppend = '';
  var w = jQuery(window).width();
  console.log('Width: ', w);
  switch(w) {
    case 1200:
        var urlAppend = '?url/suffix/example/3/';
      break;
    case 768:
        var urlAppend = '?url/suffix/example/2/';
      break;
    default:
        var urlAppend = '?url/suffix/example/1/';
    }

  var fullUrl = defaultUrl + urlAppend;
  jQuery('.class').attr('href', fullUrl);
}
jQuery(window).resize(function() {
  drawNewUrl();
});
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  drawNewUrl(); // for onload 
});
```